# encodeURIComponent or Escape in VB6

Tags: jquery, xml, asp-classic, vb6, escaping

Is there a encodeURIComponent or Uri.EscapeDataString in VBScript that can be used in an classic ASP page?

I need this function to generate jQuery parseable XML.

Server.HTMLEncode does not do a complete job.

Comment: Since ASP pages are VBScript and not VB6 (except when they use JScript, Perl, etc.) the alternatives available in VB6 will not help, they are all API calls that scripting doesn't support.  There are a number of URL encoding and decoding calls in SHLWAPI.DLL for example but script can't use them, though without more info I can't say whether they'd help you even if it could.  But maybe one of the JScript methods might work for you.

Comment: Do you mean classic ASP pages or VB6 application? For VB6, see MSDN [Using the .NET Framework Class Library from VB6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719110).

Comment: Updated description based on comments above: I need a VBScript solution for a classic ASP page. We are stuck with a character "VT" when viewed with NotePad++ (but there could be more)

Comment: A response is not expected to be url encoded, jQuery should be able to parse whatever valid XML it receives. If you see VT (presumably Vertical Tab) in the response, fix it on the server side or return the response as text, replace it in js an re-parse to XML

Answer (score 1):

You can just escape the characters yourself if you would like, according to this link, there are only five: [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents?rq=1)

Therefore, something like this should work:

```
//usage
EncodedXML = XMLEncode(MyDecodedXML)

//function
Function XMLEncode(str)
  XMLEncode = str
  If varType(XMLEncode) < 2 Exit Function
  XMLEncode = Replace(XMLEncode,Chr(34),"&quot;")
  XMLEncode = Replace(XMLEncode,"'","&apos;")
  XMLEncode = Replace(XMLEncode,"<","&lt;")
  XMLEncode = Replace(XMLEncode,">","&gt;")
  XMLEncode = Replace(XMLEncode,"&","&amp;")
End Function
```

Otherwise, this is generally done using the `MSXML2.DOMDocument` object in VBS.  Documentation is available [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/fcc6dcc3-716f-4dfe-b9e7-6559df4c5d60/MSXML2.DOMDocument).  A simple example of its use is ...

```
sFilePath = "D:\someplace\somefile.xml"
sXPath = "/SomeName/Someproperty"

Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
oXMLDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
oXMLDoc.Async = False
oXMLDoc.Load sFilePath
If (oXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
   Set oErr = oXMLDoc.ParseError
   WScript.Echo "Could not load file " & sFilePath _
              & " , error: " & oErr.Reason
   WScript.Quit
End If

Set objNames = oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(sXPath)
For Each obj in objNames
  with obj
    wsh.echo .nodeName,  .getAttribute("name")
  end with
Next
```

Comment: We somehow seem to have ASCII control characters like "VT" in the text. Will the above code handle that?

Comment: You might want to look at the second example then which will handle all encoding needed