# VB 6.0 - Open Default Email Client and Populate some Entries

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I recently made an app in `VB 2010` and in order to make it individual from the .Net Framework, I begun remaking the app in `VB 6.0`.

I have a button that is supposed to open the Default Email Client and populate the body with the text from a textbox.

In `VB 2010` it works like this :

```
Process.Start("mailto:test@email.com?subject= &body=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Textbox1.Text))
```

Can you help me find a way to do what the above does in `VB 6.0` ?

Comment: Remember that while your VB 6 application will not depend on the .Net Framework, it will instead depend on the VB6 Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, use the [ShellExecute API](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238245):

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
"ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation _
   As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters _
   As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd _
   As Long) As Long

Private Sub myButton_Click()
    ShellExecute Me.hWnd, "open", "mailto:test@email.com?subject= &body=" & Textbox1.Text, _
                 vbNullString, vbNullString, 1
End Sub
```

If you want escape your `TextBox1.Text`, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906657/encodeuricomponent-or-escape-in-vb6).

Comment: Thank you BishopBarber and sry fro responding 2 days later. I pasted the declare Function in General (Declarations) and I get this error "Compile Error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules." Where am I supposed to declare the function ?

Comment: I just needed to add a Private in front of declare and the compiler accepted it. Ty very much.

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΓιαννιώτης I'm glad you worked it out. Normally, you should declare the function in the declaration section of a module instead of placing it in the form code. Several VB6 programs contain modules that are nothing but declarations.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 specific

> **Shell Function**
>
> Runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double) representing the program's task ID if successful, otherwise it returns zero.
>
> Syntax

```
Shell(pathname[,windowstyle])
```

> The Shell function syntax has these named arguments:
>
> Part Description 
>   pathname Required; Variant (String). Name of the program to execute and any required arguments or command-line switches; may include directory or folder and drive. 
>   windowstyle Optional. Variant (Integer) corresponding to the style of the window in which the program is to be run. If windowstyle is omitted, the program is started minimized with focus.
>
> The windowstyle named argument has these values:

```
Constant Value Description 
vbHide 0 Window is hidden and focus is passed to the hidden window.  
vbNormalFocus 1 Window has focus and is restored to its original size and position. 
vbMinimizedFocus 2 Window is displayed as an icon with focus. 
vbMaximizedFocus 3 Window is maximized with focus. 
vbNormalNoFocus 4 Window is restored to its most recent size and position. The currently active window remains active. 
vbMinimizedNoFocus 6 Window is displayed as an icon. The currently active window remains active.
```

> Remarks
>
> If the Shell function successfully executes the named file, it returns the task ID of the started program. The task ID is a unique number that identifies the running program. If the Shell function can't start the named program, an error occurs.
>
> Note   By default, the Shell function runs other programs asynchronously. This means that a program started with Shell might not finish executing before the statements following the Shell function are executed.